# retrieving values from a finished running python script

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have a question related with python, anyway i have a script that has finished running, i give script1.py for example :

```
#script1.py
def test():
    x=1
    return x

val=test()
```

the question is how to retrieve script1.py after it has finished running?

i am doing something like this using script2.py but script1.py starts running again :

```
#sript2.py
import script1
val2=script1.val
```

do you know how to just retrieve the value from script1.py without restarting script1.py ??
any answer is appreciated, thx before

Comment: write it to a text file and read from the text file. since you need persistence, you need some storage and let it be a simple text file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code.

```
from script1 import x
```

Example:
**script1:**

```
c = 10
```

**script2:**

```
from script1 import c
print(c)
```

Comment: thx for the response, i have tried your solution but it still calls the function from script1...what i want to expect for the result is script1 won't restart calling function again when i try to retrieve its value after script1 has run once..

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at what running script 1 does.

```
#script1.py 
def test():  # This defines a function, not an object
    x=1
    return x

val=test() # This assigns the object val={int}1
```

So what happens in script2 follows

```
#script2.py
import script1 # Evaluates the whole context of script1, which will "rerun" it
val2=script1.val # This value can only be "carried over" because it was reevaluated
```

Since the script is ran in two separate instances, the original value from script1 will not be saved, as it will be wiped out with the rest of the objects in script1.

e.g. If I rewrite script1 to the following, script2 will always crash:

```
#script1.py changed to break script2
def test():
    x=1
    return x

# Syntax for saying, only evaluate this value if I execute this, not on import
if __name__ == '__main__':
    val=test()
```

If you need the value to "persist" between contexts here you will need to to put that somewhere else. A simple way, or one of the first ways I learned how to, would be to pickle your data out to a file and read it back in script2.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-python-pickling-example/

```
#script1.py pickling
import pickle
pickled_output='s1.pkl'

def test():
    x=1
    return x

# Syntax for saying, only evaluate this value if I execute this, not on import
if __name__ == '__main__':
    val=test()
    with open(pickled_output,'wb') as pickled_file:
        pickle.dump(val, pickled_file)

#script2.py pickling
import pickle
import s1

with open(s1.pickled_output,'rb') as pickled_output:
    val2 = pickle.load(pickled_output)
```

This is nice because it is flexible to many types of objects and can make it clearer what you are doing in each stage. Plus it will raise an error if the file doesn't exist!